# Very close to working - var_prefix= tabbed and nested

Tags: templates, playa, template-scripting, nesting

This almost works. its just on load it does not display correctly (all the tab options stack instead nesting) but once you start clicking the tabs they all work fine. (Please also note that when built in flat fashion all tabs work correctly).

The page looks like this:
niwot.colorado.edu/index.php/location/test_location

My code looks like this:

```
      <ul class="pill tabs-content contained">
         {exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" sort="asc" var_prefix="thirdorder"}
         <li {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{thirdorder:url_title}Tab">
           <div class="row">                                     
             <div class="twelve columns"> 
               {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br />

               {thirdorder:exp:playa:children field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" sort="asc" var_prefix="fourthorder"}
                 {fourthorder:title}
               {/thirdorder:exp:playa:children}

             </div>
           </div>
         </li>
        {/exp:playa:children}  
        </ul>
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What do you mean by "flat fashion"? It sounds as if you aren't firing the relevant javascript at the correct time. It should be fired when the page content has loaded.

Comment: straight forward hmnl/css/js no EE database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you issue is that all your records have *class="active"*.
It is happens because  **count** is going from *exp:channel:entries* and for all playa records is the same - 1. You have already *var_prefix* parametr for *playa:children*, so you just need to add it into condition.

```
  <ul class="pill tabs-content contained">
         {exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" sort="asc" var_prefix="thirdorder"}
         <li {if '{thirdorder:count}' == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{thirdorder:url_title}Tab">
           <div class="row">                                     
             <div class="twelve columns"> 
               {thirdorder:summary_3rd_order}<br />

               {thirdorder:exp:playa:children field="4th_order_under_3rd_order" sort="asc" var_prefix="fourthorder"}
                 {fourthorder:title}
               {/thirdorder:exp:playa:children}

             </div>
           </div>
         </li>
        {/exp:playa:children}  
        </ul>
```

Comment: All and all I spent a lot of time on this little chunk of code and this was the final piece THANKS SO MUCH.